# Cannot deploy on rinkeby network using truffle

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I'm trying to deploy simple crowdsale coin on the rinkeby test network. I'm using https://github.com/gustavoguimaraes/my-ico as template, where my code is at https://github.com/nmiculinic/shitcoin  ; master commit; hash 599edc5d5a7d1c614d64fb43f96e19bdab9e8252

However I'm unable to get this simple coin deployed to the rinkeby test network (nor the gustav's one for that matter) with the following error:

```
shitcoin (master) ✔ truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby                   
Compiling ./contracts/Shitcoin.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/BasicToken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20Basic.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'rinkeby'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x0bd42558d2daba72c886b369a492d1432397d9d617d14ce6655e1723b1d03058
  Migrations: 0xb5b69afbaf45bdfb3e3fd73164259a6cd55d031a
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xb3f5e8d87729e05b258fa97fda467d068e68c2903b60b8dc3989631c2e804262
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying ShitCoinCrowdsale...
  ... 0x113fbb45883d804a6befe05d3fa9ef940ecc2ab02196abc830b5b994064e57cc
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
    at Object.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:222830:46)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:35149:25
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:224768:9
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66971:11
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:208348:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:209773:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67130:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67420:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67575:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67535:24)
```